# Why is Chrome trying to autofill inputs with the name "search" with a username?

Tags: forms, google-chrome, input

I'm not looking for a way to stop Chrome from auto-filling as there are plenty of solutions already.

I'm looking for the answer to, why is Chrome trying to autofill this input?

```html
<input type="text" name="search">
```

[image]

It frustrates me that an input with the name "search" is being treated as a username by Chrome. "Search" is such a broad term and has no association with a username that I can think of.

Comment: Not enough info to determine if this is a programming problem, or a program specific (Chrome) problem.

Comment: see, for more info: https://superuser.com/questions/171198/remove-auto-complete-field-entries-in-google-chrome